# Typeahead not suggesting for second option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have two typeahead inputs, first one is running fine and printing Customers names,
second one is having an issue, after looking at the console I can see that the view is being executed and is returning some results, but it is not appearing in the field. any help is appreciated as I am stuck and I have literally checked every question for an answer with no luck.

creates.blade.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
      <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Customer Name:</strong>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="customer_id" id='cust' onkeypress="myFunction()" placeholder="Customer Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Card Number:</strong>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="card_id" id='card' onkeypress="myFunction1()" placeholder="Card Number">
            </div>
function myFunction()
{
  var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
  $('#cust').typeahead({
    name: 'cust',
      source:  function (query, process) {
      return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
              return process(data);
          });
      }
  });
}
function myFunction1()
{
  var path = "{{ route('autocompletecard') }}";
  $('#card').typeahead({
    name: 'card',
      source:  function (query, process) {
      return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
              return process(data);
          });
      }
  });
}

Controllers:

    public function autocomplete(Request $request)
          {
              $data = Customer::select("name")
                      ->where("name","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
                      ->get();

              return response()->json($data);
          }
          public function autocompletecard(Request $request)
              {
                  $data = Card::select("number")
                          ->where("number","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
                          ->get();

                  return response()->json($data);
              }
```

routes:

```
    Route::get('autocomplete', 'AssigneeController@autocomplete')->name('autocomplete');
Route::get('autocompletecard', 'AssigneeController@autocompletecard')->name('autocompletecard');
```

I am getting correct results on the console and but not being prompted to have results displayed on the screen.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong with your syntax, can you tell me what typeahead plugin you are using with jquery?

Comment: updated my question to include typeahead can scripts